# two duplicated indexes different sizes

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have two duplicated indexes with same row count and the same columns, only one is [22,488,980 rows; 672.7MB] and the other is [22,488,980 rows; 3.9GB]

How is this possible?

The columns for the index are as follows:
index 1:

[3 KEYS] user_hour_log_user_id {int 4}, user_hour_log_out_type_id {tinyint 1}, user_hour_log_id {bigint 8} [1 INCLUDE]  user_hour_log_out_time {datetime 8}

Reads: 764,131,409 (764,131,409 seek) Writes:3,051,570

22,488,980 rows; 672.7MB

index 2:

[3 KEYS] user_hour_log_user_id {int 4}, user_hour_log_out_type_id {tinyint 1}, user_hour_log_id {bigint 8}

Reads: 0 Writes:3,051,570

22,488,980 rows; 3.9GB

I have used sp_BlitzIndex by Brent Ozar

Comment: Just a stab. Perhaps the database shares index information? Is one unique, the other not?

Comment: No, both regular non clustered, but i did notice difference in fillfactor, a huge one.

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/04/five-things-about-fillfactor/

Answer (score 4):

As commented in the other answer, the problem is the FILLFACTOR option set to 10 in the second index.

FILLFACTOR=10 means that only 10% of a page file will be filled, while FILLFACTOR=95 means 95% of a page will be.

A FILLFACTOR=10 option means your index will use 10 times more pages (and thus, size) that it needs. A data page file is 8KB. 10% of 8KB is 800B. One row of data of the second index is 4+1+8 = 13B, so the engine is able to write 63 rows per data page file. On the first index, it uses 95% of 8KB, so 7600B. One row is 4+1+8+8 = 21. The engine can write 361 rows/page, 5.7 times more than 63 rows. This ratio is roughly the same as 3900MB/672MB, the ratio of the sizes of the two indexes.

I wouldn't recommend in any situation a fillfactor of 10.

Imagine a bookshelf. An index is like a bookshelf: you store books (rows) in alphabetical order. FILLFACTOR=100 means that when you are tidying (rebuilding) your bookshelf, you leave no space in any bookshelf's row (the data page).

A FILLFACTOR=90 means you leave 10% of the row's space left (10% of the data page file).

A FILLFACTOR=10 means you leave 90% of the space left.

Now, why does that help us? Well, if you acquire new books (insert new rows) in the bookshelf, if you have some space left on the row, you can insert the book without moving any other book in other rows. If your FILLFACTOR=100, no luck, you'll need to make space for your book, and move other books in the previous or next row.

This is called [PAGE SPLITTING and has a performance impact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms177459(v=sql.90)), because this generates extra IO. That's why it's recommended to decrease the fillfactor on indexes that you know will be frequently modified, to reduce the number of page splits.

You can read Brent Ozar's paper here to get more recommendation about fillfactor options:

https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/fill-factor/

Cheers.

Comment: I was just adding a comment recommending that you post your comment to Gordon's answer as an answer. +1

Comment: Don't forget you'll need [to rebuild that index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/172197/can-fill-factor-be-changed-on-specific-tables-without-index-rebuild)

Answer (score 0):

If these indexes are the same columns on the same table, then you are probably witnessing index fragmentation in action.  There are many resources that describe this in detail (such as [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4331/sql-server-index-fragmentation-overview/) one).  Here I just want to give you an idea of what is happening.

When you create an index on a table, it should be built quite efficiently -- exactly the data structure needed for the table.

However, when you start `insert`ing, `delete`ing, and `update`ing records, the index changes.  In particular, values are not added at the end of the index but "in the middle".  New space needs to be found, so an existing index page is split into two partially filled pages.  This process contributes to index fragmentation.

So, if you defined an index on an empty table and then inserted rows, you probably have a fragmented index.  If you created an index on the same columns after the table was populated, it will be a sleek, efficient index.

Comment: Probably not fragmentation, both rebuilt last night,  the one with the include is 8% and the other without include column is less than 1%.
But I did notice the smaller index has FILLFACTOR=95 and the other has FILLFACTOR=10.

Is this the cause of different sizes?

Comment: FILLFACTOR=10 is insanity. @katinovikov why would this be chosen? Change that to 100. :)_

Comment: @katinovikov Exactly. FILLFACTOR=10 means that only 10% of a page file will be filled, while FILLFACTOR=95 means 95% of a page will be. A FILLFACTOR=10 option means your index will use 10 times more pages (and thus, size) that it needs. Remember that a data page file is 8KB. 10% of 8KB is 800B. One row of data of your second index is 4+1+8 = 13B. You'll be able to write 63 rows per data page file. On your first index, you use 95% of 8KB, so 7600B. One row is 4+1+8+8 = 21. You can write 361 rows/page, 5.7 times more than 63 rows. This ratio is roughly the same as 3900MB/672MB.